# Getting error while converting jqPlot graph to PNG

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have developed one page which contains several graphs which is generated dynamically after page load (on some specific event). I have successfully generated graph in all browsers. But I have to give printing functionality to those graph. For that I have to convert graph canvas in to PNG inage. In all browsers this is working fine but in IE7 and IE8 it's not working.

I have used this function to convert graph canvas to PNG

```
jqplotToImageElem()
```

In all other browsers it's working fine but in IE7 and IE8 I am getting this error

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'
```

Also I have set all jqPlot js files and css. Can anyone point me out what is the cause?

Thanks,
Anvesh

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because they dont support `canvas` element.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 don't support canvas element.
This is why you get : 
`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'`

Read about [Explorer Canvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).